# What is "box-constrained mathematical optimization problem"?

Tags: optimization, constraints

I came across the term "box-constrained mathematical optimization problem" while reading a research paper.

Can someone please explain what 'box-constrained' and "box-constrained mathematical optimization problem" mean ?

Comment: Why was this question closed?  That is appalling. The question is self-contained in providing context. I am voting to reopen just for the principle, even though the existing answer is quite adequate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a problem where the only constraints are upper and lower bounds on the variables (which can be $\pm \infty$). Examples are:
$$\min_{x \geq 0} f(x)$$
$$\min_x \{ f(x) : 0 \leq x_i \leq 1 \; \forall i\}$$
$$\min_x \{ f(x) : l_i \leq x_i \leq u_i \; \forall i\}$$